# How do we find the number of solutions of an equation subject to certain constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the equation
$$
x + y + z + u = 29
$$
subject to the constraints
$$
x \geq 1 \;,\quad
y \geq 2 \;,\quad
z \geq 3 \; \quad\text{and}\quad
u \geq 0 \;.
$$
How do we find the number of solutions that this equation has? A step by step explanation of the concepts will be appreciated as I am new to Linear Algebra. Thanks.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: That is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then there is a vast infinity of solutions.

Comment: That's what I thought as well but there are four options associated with the question: a)4960 b)2600 c)23751 and d)8855

Comment: This is a number theory question then.

Comment: And it's a question of a type thaat has been asked and answered on this site many times before. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274456/find-the-number-of-solution-of-equation and the questions linked there.

Comment: Hint: $23751=\frac{26\cdot27\cdot28\cdot29}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that is a rather misleading hint.

Comment: As for the topic of there being infinitely many solutions, there would be infinitely many solutions if we didn't have the limitation that $x,y,z,u$ were strictly non-negative integers.  If one or more were allowed to be negative integers, or if we were taking solutions over the rationals or reals for example, then we would of course have infinitely many solutions.  That there are only finitely many solutions for the actual problem being asked should be obvious as $30^4$ is an easy finite upper bound to the number of solutions as there are only $30^4$ tuples of nonnegative integers less than 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the problem from finding integer solutions of $\begin{cases} x+y+z+u=29\\x\geq 1\\y\geq 2\\z\geq 3\\u\geq 0\end{cases}$

to instead finding the number of integer solutions to $\begin{cases}x'+y'+z'+u'=23\\x'\geq 0\\y'\geq 0\\z'\geq 0\\u'\geq 0\end{cases}$

From here, apply the technique of [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

With $k$ unknowns adding up to $n$ where each unknown may be any non-negative integer, there are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ solutions.  In our specific case, that is $\binom{23+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{26}{3}=2600$ solutions.